# Open Accordion Form Panel on ASP.NET Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, accordion

I have a single form written using ASP.NET MVC which I have split into three sections using JQuery-UI accordion: Info, Contact, and Payment.

I have set up a PaymentViewModel with necessary data annotations for validation. The view was created with the built-in scaffolding, then afterwards, I have been making modifications from there.

When I click submit the form validates correctly (not 100% sure if it is client or server side).  However, if the user fills out the first accordion tab correctly (Info) but ignores the rest and clicks submit, the form does not appear to submit.

It displays all the information entered in the first tab and if you manually click the second or third tabs, it displays validation error messages next to the input boxes in the 2nd and 3rd tabs..

What I would like it to do it activate the tab with the first instance of a validation error, so the user knows what they have missed. i.e. in the above example the second tab opens when they click submit.

I have tried adding the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CreatePayment').submit(function () {

        $('#CreatePayment').validate({
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                if (validator.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
                    validator.showErrors();
                    var index = $(".input-validation-error")
                        .closest(".ui-accordion-content")
                        .index(".ui-accordion-content");
                    console.log(index);
                    $(".accordion").accordion("option", "active", index);
                }
            },
            ignore: [],
        });

    });
});
```

But it is still doing the same thing.. 
Does anyone know of  method to achieve what I have described above?

Simplified details:
PaymentViewModel:

```
// Tab1
[Required]
public String Info1 { get; set; }
[Required]
public String Info2 { get; set; }
[Required]
public String Info3 { get; set; }

// Tab2
[Required]
public String Name { get; set; }
[Required]
public String Address { get; set; }
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public String Email { get; set; }

// Tab3
[Required]
public String ccName{ get; set; }
[Required]
public String CardNo{ get; set; }
[Required]
public String ccExpiry{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreatePayment" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

...
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Info</h3> <!-- Tab1 -->
    .. UNTOUCHED SCAFFOLDED FORM ... 

    <h3>Contact</h3> <!-- Tab2 -->
    .. UNTOUCHED SCAFFOLDED FORM ... 

    <h3>Payment</h3> <!-- Tab3 -->
    .. UNTOUCHED SCAFFOLDED FORM ... 

    @section Scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#CreatePayment').submit(function () {
                $('#CreatePayment').validate({
                    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                        if (validator.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
                            validator.showErrors();
                            var index = $(".input-validation-error")
                                .closest(".ui-accordion-content")
                                .index();
                            console.log(index);
                            $(".accordion").accordion("option", "active", index);
                        }
                    },
                    ignore: [],
                });

            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks.

I tried using the Chrome javascript debugger, putting a breakpoint on the `console.log(index);` but the code never stopped there. 
further investigation showed it only stopped when a breakpoint is placed on the `$('#CreatePayment').validate({` line. anything after that just gets skipped?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your only problem is with these lines:

```
var index = $(".input-validation-error")
    .closest(".ui-accordion-content")
    .index(".ui-accordion-content");
```

When you pass a selector to `index` it looks for that selector *in the current context*. In other words, it's trying to find the index of `.ui-accordion-content` *inside* `.ui-accordion-content`. That's pretty obviously not correct. If you change it to:

```
var index = $(".input-validation-error")
    .closest(".ui-accordion-content")
    .index();
```

It should then work as it will return the index of the currently selected jQuery element (`.ui-accordion-content`)

Comment: I updated the script as you suggested. However it is still doing the same thing. I also updated the question with debug tests.